# Syntax Error - Copying Data into a new table

Tags: max

I've a problem with the code in Microsoft Access

I would like to copy data from columns in an existing table into a new table then append details to the bottom of a new table for the next portfolio

The column headings aren't needed. I essentially want to copy all the columns

**CODE**

```
SELECT Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice 
INTO "2010 extract - Feb"
FROM BarePortHistory
WHERE BarePortHistory.Pcode ="SGXEE1"
ORDER BY BarePortHistory.Date

INSERT INTO 2010 extract - Feb (Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice)
SELECT Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice 
FROM BarePortHistory
WHERE BarePortHistory.Pcode ="RTXDG1"
ORDER BY BarePortHistory.Date

INSERT INTO 2010 extract - Feb(Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice)
SELECT Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice 
FROM BarePortHistory
WHERE BarePortHistory.Pcode ="SPXUY1"
ORDER BY BarePortHistory.Date
```

Is it my use of quotation marks?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

1. A table name composed of a few words (**which is not recommended!**)
   should be enclosed in square brackets: `[2010 extract - Feb]`.
2. you select all data from one table, then use `Or` to include data matching either condition.

   ```
   SELECT Date, PCode, Security, Units, BarVal, BarPrice, MktPrice 
   INTO [2010 extract - Feb]
   FROM BarePortHistory
   WHERE BarePortHistory.Pcode ="SGXEE1" OR BarePortHistory.Pcode ="RTXDG1" OR BarePortHistory.Pcode ="SPXUY1"
   ORDER BY BarePortHistory.Date
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Insert into new_table_Name(field1,field2....)
select field1,field2 ... from old_table_name
where condition

There should be no ORDER BY while inserting data to table ..Try this

Comment: I think the ORDER BY doesn't matter. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As marlan said, try changing

```
INTO "2010 extract - Feb"
```

To

```
INTO [2010 extract - Feb]
```

And your use of quotation marks in your WHERE clauses should be using single quotes.

Like so:

```
WHERE BarePortHistory.Pcode ='SGXEE1'
```

Comment: Double quotes are a fine String identifier in MS Access SQL. `"SGXEE1"`=`'SGXEE1'`

Comment: Ah okay, I guess I'm unfamiliar with MS Access SQL syntax then. I know in other programs that will throw errors.